# awk match string and sum column values

Tags: awk, grep

I'm trying to match the word `United States` from a folder containing 5 csv files, However, the command I'm using checks for single occurrence in the line. I also want to sum other two columns based on the matched string.

```
awk -F "," '{if (/United States/) sum_1 += $2;sum_2 += $3} END {print sum_1, sum_2}' Files/*.csv
```

Yes I'm trying to check more than one occurrences in the line with `awk`.

So if the line has two occurrences of United States it should give :

```
2
```

```
awk '/United States/{x++;}END{print x}' Files/*csv
```

Example file

```
United States,1,2,3
Donald TRump,1,2,3
United States,1,2,3,United States
```

Comment: @thanasisp Updated

Comment: What about this first line of code you showed us, where you want to sum the second and third column values? It doesn't seem to play any role in the accepted answer anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/United States/ {i++} END {print i}' RS=",|\n" Files/*.csv
```

`RS` - The input record separator, by default a newline.

Comment: I tried this,and I get the count as 3500 but with grep -o "United States" *.csv | wc -l I get 3502. Why the difference in awk?

Comment: The discrepancy between your `grep -o <pattern> *.csv | wc -l` output and the awk-based solution above could come from the fact that occurrences of the sought pattern may have neither a comma nor a CR to separate them, just any other character including space and tab. If so, my solution covers those cases.

Answer (score 0):

### awk

You can use the string function [gsub](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), which returns the number of substitutions made per line. This is a convenient way to count occurences per line, and you do it for all lines, so you count all of them.

```bsh
awk '{cnt += gsub(/United States/,"&")} END {print cnt}' *.csv
```

If you want to use this check inside an awk script, like in your example, you can have a syntax like:

```bsh
awk '{ if (gsub(/pattern/"&")) {"do stuff here"} }' file
```

or

```bsh
awk '{x = gsub(/pattern/"&"); "do stuff with x here"; }' file
```

---

### grep

Also using `grep`, with `-o` we will get one line per match in the output, and the count of the output lines is the result.

```bsh
grep -o "United States" *.csv | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample input file you provided, @nezabudka's answer:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=",|\n"} /United States/ {i++} END {print i}' inputFile
```

seems correct. This prompts me to ask you: are you certain that your sample input file is representative of all your field-separators ? If not, here is an alternate solution which admits input file cases such as:

```
> cat inputFile
United States,1,2,3
Donald TRump,1,2,3 United States blih blah \!?# bluh  United States
United States,1,2,3,United    States

> awk 'BEGIN {RS=",|\n| "} 
       /United/ {rec=NR; next} 
       /States/ && NR==rec+1 {i++} 
       END {print i}'  inputFile
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Command

```
    #/bin/bash

    awk '{print gsub("United States",$0)}' filename| awk 'BEGIN{sum=0}{sum=sum+$1}END{print sum}'
```